# How should I start working out to burn fat

Tags: workout

Im 14 year old 1.75/1.73. I weight 61 kg/134 pounds, I do swimming(daily), taekwondo(only saturdays), and really just that. Im skinny but I have a little much of belly fat. Im not really strong. I dont have money for a gym, but in my house I got some 1kg/2pounds weights. I also eat a lot, and have a lot of free time

Comment: At that age and mass I wouldn't care too much about body fat, but rather building strength and good routines. You'll be ready when the hormones start kicking in.

Answer (score 3):

#### You have a healthy body weight.

Your BMI computes to about 20, which is perfectly healthy. Losing weight could potentially take you in an unhealthy direction. Instead, focus on establishing good lifestyle habits such as regular aerobic exercise and resistance training. This could look like a brisk walk or short jog a few times a week, and a no-equipment-required calisthenics type bodyweight workout a few times a week. Additionally, focusing on getting adequate protein, for your weight about 100 grams per day, and eating lots and fruits and vegetables of many different colors will set you up for success down the road in maintaining a health promoting lifestyle.